# Adding the difference between two dates to another date in php

Tags: php, date, date-difference, dateinterval

I have a series of multiple different dates and I want to change them all by the same number. I only know the new date value of the first of the dates.

If I wanted to increase them all by the same value, I thought id just substract the current date from the new date to get the Time difference and add that to all the other dates. How would i go about doing that? I know the add function but this is done using a DateInterval, which i have no idea to create out of a date.

Example: i have the dates 
2016-01-19 00:00, 
2016-02-19 00:00,
2016-02-19 00:00 and i know the first one has to get changed to 
2016-01-20 00:00. Based on the difference between them i want to calculate how much i have to increase the other 2 dates by.

So basically

```
$Interval = strtotime(16-01-20 00:00) - strtotime(16-01-19 00:00);

$newTime = strtotime(16-02-19 00:00) + $Interval;
```

I solved the problem now, which was that i had put the $Interval in a strtotime aswell. I overread that completely, thinking it wasn't the cause of the error

Comment: Add the code you have tried. And some examples.

Comment: What code you're using PHP DateTime or Date function?

Comment: I just found the error. it was a problem tied to string to time conversion. i overlooked all this time. but ill post some examples

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. may help you.

```
<?php
   $datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
   $datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-19');
   $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
   echo $interval->format('%R%a days');

   $datetime3 = "2010-09-17";
   echo $newthirddata = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datetime3. $interval->format('%R%a days')));
   ?>
```